# Can't access iPhone device after installing Xcode 11 and iOS 13

Tags: xcode, passwords, updates, device, keychain

I recently installed latest Xcode 11 update and iOS 13 on my iPhone device. When I started the the device it said code sign  wants to use a keychain key and asks me for a password. I tried my usual passwords but with no luck - the passwords don't work. I have used the iPhone device before many times, so I'm confident it has something to do with my recent updates.

I tried accessing my keychain, and found the key in question, but there is no way to look at passwords for keys, this is only available under the password category as far as I know. I took a look under the passwords to see if there was something associated with Xcode or the key. I tried a few but with no luck.

So what's going on here? What password does the device want? How do I get a hold of it? If that can't be done, is there some way I can just reset the device and start from scratch with certificates and such?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it on my own. Posting here if someone runs in to the same problem. Anyway, in keychain I deleted the certificate, then in Xcode there came an immediate error under `signing and capabilities` saying that the certificate was missing. There was a button called `revoke`. I pressed it and the certificate was added agin to keychain. I ran the app on the device again asked me again for a password. This time the password worked and I could get access to the device.

Honestly I have no idea what the issue was or why it was solved this way, but there you go.